# PHP Markdown tagging last chunk of content as h3

Tags: php, markdown

I'm using [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) (version 1.0.1n, updated October 2009) to display text saved to a database in markdown format. I'm running into a strange issue where it's tagging the last chunk of every entry as an H3. When I search the markdown.php file, though, there isn't a single instance of H3.

Here are two pieces of text from my database:

```
Since its launch, major CPG brands, endemic as well as non-endemic, have flocked to retail websites to reach consumers deep in the purchase funnel through shopping media. In this session, you will hear about:

- The prioritization of shopping media for CPG brands.

- A case study of brands on Target.com on how this retailer (and others) have introduced a new channel for brand marketers to engage consumers where they are making the majority of purchase decisions: online.

- How CPG brands are leveraging real-time data from shopping media to capture consumer insights and market trends.
```

In this one, it is tagging the LI items correctly, but inside the final LI it's tagging the actual text as H3.

```
Beyond the actual money she saves, this consumer is both empowered and psychologically gratified by getting the best value on her everyday purchases. It is essential for both marketers and retailers to focus on what motivates and activates this consumer. 

Diane Oshin will share insights on what influences her shopping behavior and then identify specific tools that activate her to buy.
```

In this one, the entire paragraph starting with Diane Oshin is tagged as an H3.

Here's the really odd thing: when I do a view source, both of them are tagged correctly; it's only when using Inspect Element that I see the H3. However, it's obvious in the actual display that the H3 tag is being applied:

example 1
[image: example 1]

example 2
[image: example 2]

Can anyone help me out?

**update**

Per a comment below, I looked for instances of H tags. I found these functions, but don't know if this is what could be causing the issue or not. They are the only place in the entire file that appears to be creating a header tag of any kind.

```
function doHeaders($text) {
        # Setext-style headers:
        #     Header 1
        #     ========
        #  
        #     Header 2
        #     --------
        #
        $text = preg_replace_callback('{ ^(.+?)[ ]*\n(=+|-+)[ ]*\n+ }mx',
            array(&$this, '_doHeaders_callback_setext'), $text);

        # atx-style headers:
        #   # Header 1
        #   ## Header 2
        #   ## Header 2 with closing hashes ##
        #   ...
        #   ###### Header 6
        #
        $text = preg_replace_callback('{
                ^(\#{1,6})  # $1 = string of #\'s
                [ ]*
                (.+?)       # $2 = Header text
                [ ]*
                \#*         # optional closing #\'s (not counted)
                \n+
            }xm',
            array(&$this, '_doHeaders_callback_atx'), $text);

        return $text;
    }
    function _doHeaders_callback_setext($matches) {
        # Terrible hack to check we haven't found an empty list item.
        if ($matches[2] == '-' && preg_match('{^-(?: |$)}', $matches[1]))
            return $matches[0];

        $level = $matches[2]{0} == '=' ? 1 : 2;
        $block = "<h$level>".$this->runSpanGamut($matches[1])."</h$level>";
        return "\n" . $this->hashBlock($block) . "\n\n";
    }
    function _doHeaders_callback_atx($matches) {
        $level = strlen($matches[1]);
        $block = "<h$level>".$this->runSpanGamut($matches[2])."</h$level>";
        return "\n" . $this->hashBlock($block) . "\n\n";
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the development version of the project? You can get it [via git](http://git.michelf.com/php-markdown/).

Comment: Look for an instance of `H` as the `3` might be added based on parser state.

Comment: @hakre - I'm updating the original post; the H tags are strange...

Comment: I'm using the most recent version available at the link I posted (version 1.0.1n, updated October 2009.)

Comment: @Blender - I just cloned the git version, then ran a file compare - the markdown.php file in the git repo is identical to the file I currently have.

Comment: EmmyS, looks like that Markdown is not the culprit here, see my answer below:

Comment: @hakre: as-is. We have a hand-rolled php/mysql intranet application. Per the project homepage I can do this: `include_once "markdown.php";
$my_html = Markdown($my_text);`, which is how we're using it.

Comment: @EmmyS - Although this won't solve your problem, bullet lists shouldn't have 2 line breaks in between bullets. You should only skip a line. If you need it styled that way (with the additional space), use CSS instead.

Comment: This is how I tried to reproduce your problem, see below. I can't. Markdown is a fresh cloned copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce what you describe with the version you've been given:

```
<?php
include(__DIR__.'/php-markdown/markdown.php');


$testText = 'Since its launch, major CPG brands, endemic as well as non-endemic, have flocked to retail websites to reach consumers deep in the purchase funnel through shopping media. In this session, you will hear about:

- The prioritization of shopping media for CPG brands.

- A case study of brands on Target.com on how this retailer (and others) have introduced a new channel for brand marketers to engage consumers where they are making the majority of purchase decisions: online.

- How CPG brands are leveraging real-time data from shopping media to capture consumer insights and market trends.
';

$resultText = Markdown($testText);

var_dump($resultText);
```

The output looks fairly as you might expect it

```
string(649) "<p>Since its launch, major CPG brands, endemic as well as non-endemic, have flocked to retail websites to reach consumers deep in the purchase funnel through shopping media. In this session, you will hear about:</p>

<ul>
<li><p>The prioritization of shopping media for CPG brands.</p></li>
<li><p>A case study of brands on Target.com on how this retailer (and others) have introduced a new channel for brand marketers to engage consumers where they are making the majority of purchase decisions: online.</p></li>
<li><p>How CPG brands are leveraging real-time data from shopping media to capture consumer insights and market trends.</p></li>
</ul>
"
```

I assume something else tampering the data before it get's into the markdown parser or afterwards. But based on the data, the markdown parser does not create the `<h3>` tags. You must look somewhere else :(

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. I'll have to search our stylesheets to see if something is causing this.

Comment: I don't know if you're still watching this, but I took out the call to Markdown and just printed the straight text, and there's no strange formatting. So it has to be something in the markdown function that's doing it, doesn't it?

Comment: Not on my computer, there it works perfectly. See the code I've posted.

Comment: OK, I tried your code in my app, and when I do a var_dump I get something like this: `A case study of brands on Target.com on how this retailer (and others) have introduced a new channel for brand marketers to engage consumers where they are making the majority of purchase decisions: online.
How CPG brands are leveraging real-time data from shopping media to capture consumer insights and market trends.
string(1382) "` The string(1382) is NOT part of the content, and it's a different number for each record. Any idea what could be causing that?